# I need to transfer CLR output with final Select to an application

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, clr

I need to transfer the value of @error of a CLR to an application. A simple final select should do it, my Software provider told me. From a normal Stored Procedure this is no problem, but how shall I do it from CLR?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckCL
    @docpath nvarchar (100),
    @error nvarchar (200) output
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
EXTERNAL NAME [CheckCLR].[CheckCLR].[HelloWorld]
GO

"SELECT @fehler"
```

Comment: It should work like a normal procedure. Can you show how your calling it?

Comment: the procedure CheckCL works fine. It returns

Comment: ... the right result. But then I'd like to transfer this result back to the calling application. In a usual STP it is a simple SELECT xxx. Unfortunatelly I cannot show you how the STP is called, the application handles the call, I just have to define the parameters.

Comment: As I said, it should work like a normal procedure. If you're unable to show how your calling it, I'm unable to suggest alternatives.